# bad explanation in how to solve the cubic

Tags: polynomials, cubics

The question asked me to solve

> $t^3+pt+q=0$ where $p,q$ real and $27q^2+4p^3<0$ using the identity $\cos{3\theta}=4\cos^3{\theta}-3\cos{\theta}$.

Answer goes like this and I have stopped where it just makes no sense at all to me.

> Since the discriminant $-(27q^2+4p^3)>0$ implies there are three real roots this is the case here. Let $t=v \cos{\theta}$. Then
>
> $$0=t^3+pt+q=v^3\cos^3{\theta}+pv\cos{\theta}+q \implies 4\cos^3{\theta}+\frac{4p}{v^2}\cos{\theta}+\frac{4q}{v^3}=0$$
>
> as $p<0$ we may solve $v=\sqrt{-\frac{4p}{3}}$ for real $v$ and blah blah..

Whoa, where did that last statement randomly pop out from? What does it mean "as $p<0$"? Reverse engineering tells me that this only holds given that $1=-\frac{4p}{3v^2}$ is true. Where in heaven's name does that come from the equation above? Badly explained if you ask me, I cannot figure out how they Harry Potter-ed $v=\sqrt{-\frac{4p}{3}}$ right there.

What is going on? Does someone see the bizarre magic going on behind it? Great if someone would explain the trick to me because right now it just appeared out of thin air to me

Comment: I can't help you. But +1 for 'Harry potter-ed'

Comment: Where does $\;q\;$ appear in the original question?

Comment: $q$ is the constant in the equation, which is $1$.

Comment: typo, the $1$ is supposed to be $q$, apologies and let me fix that

Comment: You have hundreds of typos in there. Correct them, please.

Comment: Hope all hundreds of them have been fixed now

Comment: No. Still a $\cos^2$ instead of $\cos^3$ and no $=0$ in the end of the line. Be more careful please.

Comment: Note that the aim is to find at least one root of the equation. They introduce two new variables and later give one of them a specific value. This is ok, as long as they find a solution in the end. However, not well written - rather confusing.

Comment: $v$ and $\theta$ you are talking about, yes? But I still don't see how they managed to deduce that relationship in the question between $v$ and $p$. Or are you also saying they can come up with whatever imaginary relationship they want between variables? So I can come up with one without any logical explanation behind it so long as I arrive at a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Since $27q^2+4p^3<0$, $p^3<-(27/4)q^2<0$ so $p<0$.

Comment: I get the $p<0$ part, I meant what does it mean "AS" $p<0$ to lead to $v=\sqrt{-\frac{4p}{3v^2}}$? Can you explain that? My main question is "where did $v=\sqrt{-\frac{4p}{3v^2}}$" come from

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't get where you were confused. Then I don't know, it's quite unclear to me too.

Comment: I think they just put it in there and hope it is ok. They still have the $\theta$... Maybe one can show that when $t$ is a solution then $|t|$ is smaller than $-4p/3$. Then this substitution is completely ok.